# Find $f(x)$ given $f'$' and two initial values

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was given that $f''(x) = 6x + \frac{1}{x^2}$ , $f(1)=0$ and $f(2) = 6$. I have gotten down to $x^3 + ln(|{x}|)+Cx + D$ and I am confused on how to find the values for $Cx$ and $D$ .

Comment: I am confused. You have $f(1)=0$ and $f(2)=6$. Plugging this back to your solution to find $C$ and $D$ will solve the problem. Why shouldn't this work?

Comment: Use $f(1)=0$ to get the value of $D$, and $f(2)=6$ to get the value of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since you figured that $f(x) = x^3-\ln(|x|)+Cx+D$, plugging in $f(1)=0$ gives $0 = 1+C+D$

What happens when you plug in $f(2)=6?$

Answer (score 0):

Check your signs

$f(x) = x^3 - \ln|x| + Cx + D\\  
f(1) = 1 - 0 + C + D = 0\\
f(2) = 8 - \ln 2 + 2C + D = 6$

Now you have a system of linear equations that you should know how to solve.

Comment: I solved and got f(x) = x^3 + ln(absx) + x(-1 - ln2) + ln2. Would that be correct?

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(1)=0$, so $1^3+\ln|1|+C+D=0$, namely, $1+C+D=0$; since $f(2)=6$, so $2^3+\ln|2|+2C+D=6$. Solve this system:
$$\begin{cases}C+D=-1\\2C+D=-2-\ln2\end{cases},$$
and you get
$$C=-1-\ln 2,\,\,\, D=\ln2$$